# Docker-compose entrypoint could not locate Gemfile but works fine with docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

When I use `docker-compose up`
the container exits with code 10 and says
`Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

but if I do `docker run web entrypoint.sh`
The rails app seems to start without an issue.

What could be the cause of this inconsistent behavior?

## Entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
    rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8080
```

Relevant part from the docker-compose file.

## docker-compose.yml

```
...
  web:
    build:
      context: "./api/" 
      args:
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.7.2'
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.2.29'
    entrypoint: entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `docker run web ...`, you're running exactly what's in the image, no more and no less.  On the other hand, the `volumes:` directive in the `docker-compose.yml` file replaces the container's `/app` directory with arbitrary content from the host.  If your Dockerfile `RUN bundle install` expecting to put content in `/app/vendor` in the image, the `volumes:` hide that.

You can frequently resolve problems like this by deleting `volumes:` from the Compose setup.  Since you're running the code that's built into your image, this also means you're running the exact same image and environment you'll eventually run in production, which is a big benefit of using Docker here.

(You should also be able to delete the `tty:` and `stdin_open:` options, which aren't usually necessary, and the `entrypoint:` and those specific `build: { args: }`, which replicate settings that should be in the Dockerfile.)

(The Compose file suggests you're building a Docker image out of the `api` subdirectory, but then bind-mounting the current directory `.` -- `api`'s parent directory -- over the image contents.  That's probably the immediate cause of the inconsistency you see.)

Comment: Thank you, it indeed was the volume mounting the directory shadowing the directory contents. A bit of a follow on question - when using docker for development it would be more convenient to have local code changes reflect immediately in the running container instead of needing to rebuild the image. Any direction on best practices for achieving this?

Comment: I use `rbenv` on my host system, without Docker, for day-to-day development, even though my application ultimately gets deployed to Kubernetes.

Comment: I see, for myself it would be preferred to achieve tighter dev-prod parity but until I figure out a better solution, this will get me through for now.